# make a field disabled/read-only in SharePoint 2013 new/edit form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, edit-form, newform

I tried to make some fields disabled/readonly in the new/edit form in Sharepoint 2013. I want to use title only. See my code below. Only "textarea" works fine.  The others don't work, still editable.

```
<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*'textare...' for multiple line text works */
        $("textarea[Title='Notes']").attr("disabled", true);

        /*The code below don't work, still editable on those fields*/
        $("input[title='Release Info']").attr("disabled",true);
        $("input[title='Release Date']").attr("disabled",true);
        $("select[title='Tools']").attr("disabled",true);    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`.prop()` Vs `.attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr),

> - You usually want `prop()` rather than `attr()`.
> - In the majority of cases, prop() does what `attr()` used to do. Replacing calls to `attr()` with `prop()` in your code will generally work.
> - Properties are generally simpler to deal with than attributes. An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of any type. For example, the checked property is a Boolean, the style property is an object with individual properties for each style, the size property is a number.

And According to [Disable/enable an input with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery),

> For **jQuery 1.6+**, To change the `disabled` property you should use the [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) function.

So, you can try using your code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*'textarea...' for multiple line text works */
        $("textarea[Title^='Notes']").prop("disabled", true);

        $("input[Title^='Release Info']").prop("disabled", true); 
        $("input[Title^='Release Date']").prop("disabled", true); 
        $("select[Title^='Tools']").prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

**Note**:

I have used **Starts With**(`^=`) Selector which makes your element selection successful in some cases where your field is **Required** as in SharePoint it automatically adds `Required Field` to the `title` attribute of your field.

**For Example**:

If you have a single line of text field with display name `Release Info` and this field is **Required** then its `title` property will be like `Release Info Required Field`. In such cases `$("input[Title='Release Info']")` selector fails.

[image]

**Reference**: [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

**Additional Reference**: [Difference between `disabled` and `readonly`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht).

Answer (score 0):

The below script works for me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("textarea[Title='Notes']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("input[Title='Release Info']").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
        $("input[Title='Release Date']").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
        $("select[Title='Tools']").prop("disabled",true); }
    );
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: None of these work for disabling Name with Presence fields (or making them read only).  Please help me make name with presence field read only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$("input[Title='Release Info']").props("disabled","disabled");
```