# How to hide or disable some specific field in new form view

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to disable or hide some field while creating a new item in list.
It should be only editable while click on edit item.
[image]

Comment: By looking at the image, I suppose you are using classic experience. Do you use content editor or script editor on your site?

Comment: Trying to use script editor. Or please let me know if any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the type of your field?

Comment: it is choice & multiline field Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SPUtility.js** to hide or make ready only field in SharePoint new/edit form.

1. Download SPUtility.js.
2. Upload the downloaded file (SPUtility.js) to an appropriate place in SharePoint Site like ‘Style Library’
3. Then reference the SPUtility.js in your new form.

Then use the below code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/sputility.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function ()
{ // Hide the filed using the display name
SPUtility.GetSPField('column display name').Hide();
// Show the field
SPUtility.GetSPField('column display name').Show();
//Make read only
SPUtility.GetSPField('column display name').MakeReadOnly();

});
</script>
```

For more information:

https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/

You can download SPUtility.js from here:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sputility

If you want to hide using CSR,  kindly follow steps in the below link,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736391/sharepoint-hiding-fields-in-newform-dispform-editform

Using simple jQuery.

If you want to hide the column only in new form, you can implement the following jQuery-Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   var strText="Column Name";
   jQuery('td nobr:contains("' + strText + '")').eq(0).closest('tr').hide();
});
</script>
```

JQuery-reference files need to be referred in the Code.

Comment: Karthik, it seems not working, Can you please help me on some other way.

Comment: What error you are getting??

Comment: SPUtility.js seems harmfull & unable to download it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you karthik for your effort on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      //Show or hide columns  

      $('nobr:contains("Field1")').closest('tr').hide(); 
      $('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').hide();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of Field1 and Field2 use the name of your columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ganesh, It worked for me. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Welcome. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: Ganesh, Code was working fine yesterday, Today i have deleted the list & created a new list, I am trying to hide the field in new form , it is working without any issue but unable to save the item. please help me on this.

Comment: Is it hiding the fields? Are you hiding any required field? Are you getting any error in browser console while saving the item?

Comment: Ganesh, You r just a tech..Yes i was hiding the required field. I removed the same, It is working now.

Comment: Ganesh, How can i keep a field in readonly in edit mode (Mean to say, it will be writeable in new form not in edit form.

Comment: You need to edit the `...Lists/ListName/EditForm.aspx` page and add script editor in it....and use code like `$("select[Title^='Tools']").prop("disabled", true);`. Check my answer given here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270110/make-a-field-disabled-read-only-in-sharepoint-2013-new-edit-form/270145#270145. Upvote if it works for you :P

Comment: I couldn't understood here, Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you hide these fields in NewForm.aspx.

You can create a new "new form" in SharePoint designer or hide fields with the powershell command.

There's a similar issue here:

[Hide some fields in the NewForm.aspx for a custom list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77986/hide-some-fields-in-the-newform-aspx-for-a-custom-list)

Comment: How can i do it using powershell

Comment: Can you please suggest me if any other way apart from designer.